# JPA2 Criteria Accent-insensitive without database dependency

Tags: java, sql, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have this query using native query in JPA2 to search for parcial text independent of case or accents used (based on http://www.guj.com.br/java/212706-accent-insensitive-hibernate):

```
public List<Hipotesis> findHipotesisByText(String srchtext) {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();

    String textNormalized =
        Normalizer.normalize(srchtext, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "").toUpperCase();

    Query query =
        em.createNativeQuery(
            "select * from HIPOTESIS where ( UPPER(TRANSLATE( TEXTFIELD,'ÀÁÂÃáàâãÉÈÊéèêÍíÓÒÔÕóòôõÚÜúü','AAAAaaaaEEEeeeIiOOOOooooUUuu' ) ) like '%" + textNormalized + "%'",
            Hipotesis.class);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Hipotesis> results = query.getResultList();
    return results;

}
```

The search text is normalized to strip accents and is converted to upper case.
The native query uses TRANSLATE to convert accents to pure text and UPPER converts the result to upper case.

So the search text eMeRgÊ will be normalized to EMERGE and will match any occurence in the database like emergencia, emergência, Emergência.

Although TRANSLATE is specified by SQL99 it is not supported or implemented exactly like the standard.

The question: is there any way to implement this query without using TRANSLATE? or without using native query?

Comment: If you plan to do searches in a case insensitive manner and without accents, you should store your values in your database in lowercase (or uppercase but only one case) and without accents.

Comment: Well, texts could be duplicated with and without accents, but I was searching for a more elegant solution using JPA and not touching the database.

Comment: Anyway, if you want to allow indexed queries, you would have to index using the UPPER TRANSLATE function ...

Comment: @SergeBallesta The indexing will have little effect as the query condition is a `LIKE '%...%'`

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen: you are right :-( . But as an former DB admin I allways hope developpers come to using indexes when delays become excessive and users complain ...

Answer (score 2):

The most elegant solution, in my personal opinion is to actually duplicate the data and convert it to a normalized form. You're using a `LIKE` condition in your query, which basically precludes any normal (short of full-text) indexing mechanism. This means that the `TRANSLATE` query will most likely turn out to be inefficient and difficult to optimize.

Using JPA, you can make use of entity lifecycle events to manage the normalized forms in a fairly convenient manner:

```
@Entity
public class Whatever implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;

    private String string;
    private String normalizedString;

    // getters and setters

    @PreUpdate
    @PrePersist
    protected void normalize() {
        normalizedString = yourNormalizationMethod(string);
    }
}
```

I believe this to be the cleanest, most elegant, and most database-agnostic way to address this type of issue.

Comment: Unless you need to search in multiple fields at once.